# How to make core java application autostart?

Tags: windows

I have created a desktop application in Java using notepad. Now I want to make it automatically start up whenever a client machine boots up.

My folder contain some java file, one bat file and some jar file and also have a cmd file that start the application.

When it will start automatically upon computer start, it must run the cmd file in the background of the computer that cmd file must run a MyTestRunner(java class) file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create a .bat file that executes your java program. for e.g. myExecute.bat , Inside the .bat file write following command

```
 java yourClassName
```

now, create short cut of this .bat file's in startup folder.